# Does exists a class that load async image like in the flipboard app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

Does exists a class that load async image like in the flipboard app with a beautiful animation during the download time?

Comment: There is no native class but do a search here on StackOverflow and you will find many similar questions with good answers

Answer (score 1):

I would use [EGOImageLoader](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading). Worked great for all my uses.